# SQL combine 2 rows into 1 row then delete 1

Tags: sql

I'm trying to complete an SQL query homework question and cannot figure out how to add 2 rows together from the same table, with the intention of deleting one after they are combined.

I have a table name 'country', in it, I have 241 rows of data with columns.

```
name        region           area          population     GDP
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hong Kong   Southeast Asia      1040          5542869      136100000000
China       Asia             9596960       1203097268     2978800000000
```

Expected output:

```
name        region           area       population    GDP
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Hong Kong   Southeast Asia      1040       5542869     136100000000
China       Asia             9598000    1208640137    3114900000000
```

The goal is to keep the name of the row as "China" and the region as "Asia" but adding the numeric values from the "Hong Kong" row to the "China" row for the columns (area, population, and GDP).

I have tried UNION and MERGE but I'm not familiar with using them and couldn't get it to work.

I feel like it has to be something like the SQL query below:

```
update country 
set area = area.HongKong + area.China 
where name = 'China';
```

but I don't know the proper way to reference a specific row.

Comment: Please either solve your homework by yourself, or explain the problem that other people can understand the problem. Also show what you tried so far.

Comment: I cannot upload a snap shot of what I have tried because I'm too new of a user.

Comment: What is the problem with copying some text lines into the question? Maybe try the tutorial or help system!

Comment: I've been searching for hours looking at tutorials and videos and I haven't had any luck, so I thought I would try here.

Comment: "Edit" the question instead of adding more comments. You could also show a few sample database rows and how the result should look like.

Comment: Hi, sorry to keep bugging you @U.Windl  I agree with the edits you made to the post but I can't seem to make them myself.  I originally had the table in with tabs between the values so it looked nice and after I complete the edit it just smushes everything back together.

Comment: Just expand the tabs to spaces before pasting them, then mark the code-like text with the mouse and click on the "format as code" symbol (`{}`). And try not to destroy what others did correct ;-)

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to destroy anything. I actually would've preferred to go with your edits but it said that Community had rejected it.  If you could please help with the question I would appreciate it.

Comment: Improve your question by explaining what the primary key for the table is and how the statements looked that you executed (together with the result). I would recommend (for you and the users here) that you make a small example table from the big one. So example outputs are smaller, and you don't destroy your original while looking for a solution.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes, homework.  I remember those days.

Here is some code to help out -

```
--create a temp table to hold sample data
select
*
into #country
from
(
  values
  ('Hong Kong', 'Southeast Asia', 1040, 5542869, 136100000000),
  ('China', 'Asia', 9596960, 1203097268, 2978800000000),
  ('USA', 'North America', 1, 10, 100)  --some other row in table
) d ([name], region, area, population, gdp);

select * from #country;
```

Here is what the data looks like in this table:
[image]

```
--update statement
with
Totals as
(
  select
  count(1) rows,  --should be 2
  sum(area) areaTotal,
  sum(population) populationTotal,
  sum(gdp) gdpTotal
  from #country
  where [name] in ('Hong Kong', 'China') --this filter may be insufficient; it would be better to select by a primary key such as a rowID but the table does not have one
)
update c
set c.area = t.areaTotal,
c.population = t.populationTotal,
c.gdp = t.gdpTotal
from #country c
inner join totals t
on c.[name] = 'China';
```

Here is what the data looks like after the update:
[image]

There are a few noteworthy things here:

1. The code above the update statement, `with Totals as (...`, is called a common table expression (also abbreviated as CTE).  It is being used here to contain the query that calculates the totals needed to perform the update.  A CTE is one approach to creating an intermediate data set.  Alternative approaches to this include: creating a temp table or using a derived table.
2. To see the results of the query within the CTE, those lines of code can be highlighted in your editor and executed against the database.
3. The original post said there are 241 rows of data in the country table.  This means it is important to have a reliable filter in the query that calculates the totals so the correct rows for summing are isolated.  The preferred way to filter the rows is to use a primary key, such as a rowID.  Since this table does not have a primary key column, I made a guess and used the `[name]` column.
4. The purpose of `count(1) rows` in the CTE is to make sure only 2 rows are being summed.  If this number comes back as anything other than 2, it means there is a problem with the filter and the `where` clause needs to be modified.  The number of rows will only be visible when you do #2 above.

Now the Hong Kong row needs to be cleaned up:

```
--delete old row
delete from #country where [name] = 'Hong Kong';
```

This is what the data looks like now:
[image]

Again, it would be preferable to use a primary key column in the `where` clause instead of the `[name]` column to be certain that the correct row is being deleted.